# Не работает on_member_join в дискорд боте

Tags: python, бот, discord

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Private message')
```

бот просто не видит, что человек заходит на сервер, пробовал переставлять, но не работает

Comment: Какая у вас ошибка?

Comment: Спасибо ща ваш ответ, я это учту, но проблема была в другом, бот просто не видел, что человек входит на сервер, проблему удалось решить: в начале, когда объявляем префикс бота, я дописал intents = discord.Intents.all(), client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите что бы новый пользователь вашего сервера одерживал сообщения в ЛС то вам нужно написать код так:

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    member_id = member.id
    user = bot.get_user(member_id)
    await user.send('Private message')
```